# .net conditional not evaluating properly

Tags: .net, conditional-statements, try-catch, throw

I have the following simple block of code

```
  var assmSpec = util.ASSEMBLYFOLDER + task.AssemblyName; // evals to valid fileSpec
  if (!File.Exists(assmSpec))
      throw new TaskException(string.Format(
          "Assembly [{0}] cannot be located.", assmSpec));
```

Since the assembly referenced by assmSpec does in fact exist (The `File.Exists()` evals to true), I expect that the exception would *not* be thrown.  But it is.  the code steps into the throw statement.  To debug, I modified the code to read:

```
  var assmSpec = util.ASSEMBLYFOLDER + task.AssemblyName; // evals to valid fileSpec
  var asmExists = File.Exists(assmSpec);
  if (!asmExists)
      throw new TaskException(string.Format(
          "Assembly [{0}] cannot be located.", assmSpec));
```

Here, `asmExists` evals to true, and The code still steps into the throw.

I then modified the code to read:

```
  var assmSpec = util.ASSEMBLYFOLDER + task.AssemblyName; // evals to valid fileSpec
  if (!File.Exists(assmSpec) && File.Exists(assmSpec))
      throw new TaskException(string.Format(
         "Assembly [{0}] cannot be located.", assmSpec));
```

and again, the code still hits the throw.  Something is clearly very wrong here.  Has anyone have an explanation ? Am I doing something really obviously stupid here?

fwiw, this code is in a method that also has a try - catch - finally construction, but it is before all of them   (before the try) ...

---

The full method is:

```
  public void StartProcess(Task task)
    {
        log.Write(log.Level.Debug, string.Format(
            "TaskWorker.StartProcess {0} process",
            task.Name), task.Name);
        WorkerMessageManager.MsgArrvdWorkerHndlr += MsgArrvdWorkerHndlr;
        var tskName = task.Name;
        var assmSpec = util.ASSEMBLYFOLDER + task.AssemblyName;
        if (!File.Exists(assmSpec))
            throw new TaskException(string.Format(
                "Assembly [{0}] cannot be located.", assmSpec));

        try
        {
            WorkerMessageManager.NotifyWorker(new ProgressTaskMessage(
                                    tskName, "", tskName + "  starting..."));
            // -------------------------------------------
            Assembly dA;
            try { dA = Assembly.LoadFrom(assmSpec); }
            catch(FileNotFoundException nfX)
            { throw new TaskException(string.Format(
                "Assembly [{0}] cannot be located.", assmSpec), 
                nfX); }
            // -------------------------------------------
            var iTsk = (IExecuteTasks)dA.CreateInstance(task.ClassName);
            if (iTsk == null)
                throw new TaskException(
                    string.Format("Unable to instantiate {0} from {1}",
                        task.ClassName, task.AssemblyName));

            if (iTsk.TaskName != tskName) // do not execute if names do not match
                throw new TaskNameMismatchException(string.Format(
                    "CHECK CONFIGURATION SETTINGS,  Data Task Name Mismatch.{0}" +
                    "Task name defined in TaskScheduler.config [{1}], {0} does " +
                    "not match name [{2}] as defined in Task Logic assembly: {3}.{4}",
                        sNL, tskName, iTsk.TaskName, task.AssemblyName, 
                        task.ClassName),  tskName, iTsk.TaskName);
            // -------------------------------------------
            iTsk.DataImportProgressEvent += OnProgressReport;
            iTsk.ProcessCompletedEvent += OnProcessCompleted;
            iTsk.GeneralEvent += OnGeneralEvent;
            // -----------------------------------
            log.Write(log.Level.Debug, string.Format(
                  "{0} process Started", task.Name),
                  task.Name);
            if (task.JobQueue.HasJobReady)
                iTsk.StartTask(JobQueues.Instance.DeQueue(tskName));
            else iTsk.StartTask(); 
            log.Write(log.Level.Debug, string.Format(
                  "{0} process Completed", task.Name),
                  task.Name);
        }
        catch (TaskNameMismatchException inmX)
        { log.Write(log.Level.Warn, inmX.Message, tskName, inmX); }

        catch (BpaTaskException mX)
        {
            var errMsg = string.Format(
                "Error in Data Import StartProcess(). " + sNL +
                "Exception {0}: {1}, " + sNL +
                "Stack Trace: {2}",
                mX, mX.Message, mX.StackTrace); 
            log.Write(log.Level.Error, errMsg, 
                        task.Name, mX);
        }

        catch(Exception X)
        {
            var errMsg = string.Format(
                "Error in Data Import StartProcess(). " + sNL +
                "Exception {0}: {1}, " + sNL +
                "Stack Trace: {2}",
                X, X.Message, X.StackTrace);
            log.Write(log.Level.Error, errMsg, task.Name, X);

            // WorkerMessageManager.NotifyWorker(new ImportFailMessage(X));
            // This throw instruction causes the Scheduler service to stop alltogether
            // I'm Removing the throw for now, because it seems inappropriate to 
            //          kill the whole service..
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            task.IsRunning = false;
            WorkerMessageManager.MsgArrvdWorkerHndlr -= MsgArrvdWorkerHndlr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh please use curly braces even for an if with only one statement in it.

Comment: check the assigned value to the assSpec variable ...

Comment: yes assigned value is corrrect, but more importantly, when I debug in the second block, the assigned value of `asmExists` is true...

Comment: It would help to see more of the code surrounding this snippet.

Comment: I sometimes run into impossible situations like this and find that closing Visual Studio, then restarting and doing a full rebuild will solve the problem. I haven't seen it with VS 2010, but earlier versions would do it periodically.

Comment: @Jim,  yeah, I have experienced that as well... but I have tried it here...  Actually even moved the code to from client site to my home machine and installed it there.. Still getting same crazy behavior... Next step is to create a small test app and try to reproduce without the rest of the dependancies and other projects in solution...

Comment: How many threads do you have running this at the same time? If multiple threads are executing this code concurrently, your breakpoints could be catching two (or more) different tasks, and your results will be *very* confusing.

Comment: I do have multiple threads, but this scenario is a test case that only launches one task, so there is only one running here.  Plus, the launcher (in another method, checks to make sure the task is not already running before it attempts to launch it...

Comment: this is not critical, tp "fix" this, A few lines down where I attempt to load the assembly I added a trap for a `FileNotFoundException` and that works just fine, so I can simply remove this check, but this is extremely vexing that I can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Check that there is no text (code or semicolon) following the `if ()` statement on the same line. The most likely cause is that the "throw" is not actually "inside" the if statement, so it's always executed.

Check that you are debugging a DEBUG build - you may get odd values reported in the debugger for a RELEASE build, which may make it look as though a variable is true when in fact it is false.

It's also possible under some circumstances (though only usually with things like references to precompiled dlls or corrupt pdb files) to be looking at different code than you are debugging, giving the impression that changes you are making to the source are being ignored. Do a Build > Clean, check that the assembly you're running is no longer present on disk, and then rebuild it to be sure that it's up to date and in sync with your source code.

Comment: good suggestions, tried them all.   Even moved entire code solution to a fresh (different) machine in different environment .... getting same behavior.

Comment: In that case, I'd try to whittle down the code to the minimal reproducible form, and take away anything that might influcnce the results (make sure there is only one place where that exception is thrown, eliminate the nested try/catches, use bool instead of var, set a fixed pathname to a file that permanently exists and won't be open (or running) at the time, etc. This should get you to a point where you can identify what is causing the behaviour, and it may turn out to be something simple like it's actually hitting the second throw and giving an FNF exception because the file is open.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried something similar, and it works fine for me. Have you tried this using a statement block instead of a single throw line?

The compiler could be confused, and may need to be restarted. It's not unheard of. :/

Comment: see my above comments.. Have rebooted, and even moved entire solution to different machine.  And can't use a using block .  What object would I be using ?  File.Exists() is a static method.

Comment: he didn't mean a using statement. He meant (if I interpret it correctly) to use a statement block, which is to say, wrap stuff in curly braces after your if statements.

Comment: ahh. sorry, Missed that.  But no, using curly braces does not affect the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the internals of the File.Exists method, you find that it will return false under numerous circumstances including:

1. path is null or an empty string
2. The file does not exist
3. The OS thinks the file is actually a directory
4. The account trying to access the file does not have read permissions.
5. Some other internal NotSupportedException, SecurityException, IOException or UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown.

The problem is that all those potential errors are buried. I'd suggest trying the `FileInfo` class instead:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo( assmSpec );
if ( !fileInfo.Exists )
    throw new TaskException( ...
```

The constructor on FileInfo will throw one of a handful of exceptions back to you which might give you more information about the issue.